# How to persist EventEmitter object in node application?

Tags: node.js, events, eventemitter

I am connecting external websockets in my application. In those sockets I am firing EventEmitters. But, when I make update to my application all living Events dying. I want them to be alive as long as I remove them. I tried redis pub/sub, result is the same. What is the way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Store eventEmitter in Redis (or any other datastore) against the client connection or connection unique identifier so that it can be looked up later to send push message to that particular client.

Netflix zuul does same with push messaging, but it uses netty server. take a look at it

https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki/Push-Messaging